# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 desktop on a X86-64 I7 system with 8G of ram and a SCSI HD/SCSI DVD drive using a flash drive

Tags: system-installation

I am working on a medical piece of hardware that currently uses an older version of Ubuntu desktop.
I am trying to perform a fresh install using a flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. Grub comes up and Ubuntu starts to load in memory as I can see the commands scroll up my screen. The display shows the Ubuntu orange icon with the spinning wheel. After about 30 seconds the system powers off.
The strange part is I can install Ubuntu 18 desktop just fine and then perform upgrades to 22.04.
I need to install Ubuntu desktop 22.04 on multiple machines.
So what is the difference installation wise between Ubuntu 18 and 22. I even tried installing using the nomodeset option for GRUB and that did not help.
On a whim I was able to install Windows on the system with no issues.
Anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As mentioned above, install flash drive with 22.04 desktop and power system up. Grub loads then I see OS loading drivers and checking hardware. the Word Ubuntu comes up with orange circle and the spinning white circle. I am assuming that Ubuntu is being loaded into memory at this point. Then the system powers off. The system never gets to the selection of language. The strange part I have an Ubuntu 18 flash drive and it installs just fine. What's the possible issue or what's the difference between Ubuntu 18 and 20?